# How to highlight current screen (or window)?

Tags: unity, scripts, multiple-monitors, compiz, window-manager

I'm using two screen setup at work and while it usually helps more than it hurts, I have some issues with it.

One of them is problem with trailing focus - sometimes I make mistake of typing on wrong screen (focus is trailing my cursor, but it's not always easy to notice that cursor is on other screen when you do things in a rush). This is very annoying when instead of typing I cause tons of different actions (one-key-shortcuts in thunderbird).

Is there a way to better highlight active screen or window (for example using easily visible border - even for maximized windows)?

EDIT:

I think nice solution would be some kind of short animation when window receives focus.

Comment: Which DE? In gnome-shell you can use https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/891/windows-blur-effects/

Comment: @Rmano the tag sais Unity :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm oops --- true. Will leave the comment, maybe can be useful for someone googling...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Highlight the focussed screen (or dim- flash on focus change, see EDIT further below)

In a side-by-side dual monitor setup (left-right), the script below will set
the brightness of the monitor with the focussed window to "normal" (100%),
while other one is dimmed to 60%.

If the focus changes, the brightness will follow the focus:

*focus on (a window) on the right screen*
[image]

*focus on (a window) on the left screen*
[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
In a side-by-side dual monitor setup (left-right), the script below will set
the brightness of the monitor with the focussed window to "normal" (100%),
while other one is dimmed to 60%. If the focus changes, the brightness will
follow the focus
"""
import subprocess
import time

def get_wposition():
    # get the position of the currently frontmost window
    try:
        w_data = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        frontmost = subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-root", "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"]).decode("utf-8").split()[-1].strip()
        z = 10-len(frontmost); frontmost = frontmost[:2]+z*"0"+frontmost[2:]
        return [int(l.split()[2]) for l in w_data if frontmost in l][0]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def get_onscreen():
    # get the size of the desktop, the names of both screens and the x-resolution of the left screen
    resdata = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8")
    if resdata.count(" connected") == 2:
        resdata = resdata.splitlines()
        r = resdata[0].split(); span = int(r[r.index("current")+1])
        screens = [l for l in resdata if " connected" in l]
        lr = [[(l.split()[0], int([s.split("x")[0] for s in l.split() if "+0+0" in s][0])) for l in screens if "+0+0" in l][0],
               [l.split()[0] for l in screens if not "+0+0" in l][0]]
        return [span, lr]
    else:
        print("no second screen seems to be connected")

def scr_position(span, limit, pos):
    # determine if the frontmost window is on the left- or right screen
    if limit < pos < span:
        return [right_scr, left_scr]
    else:
        return [left_scr, right_scr]

def highlight(scr1, scr2):
    # highlight the "active" window, dim the other one
    action1 = "xrandr", "--output", scr1, "--brightness", "1.0"
    action2 = "xrandr", "--output", scr2, "--brightness", "0.6"
    for action in [action1, action2]:
        subprocess.Popen(action)

# determine the screen setup
screendata = get_onscreen()
left_scr = screendata[1][0][0]; right_scr = screendata[1][1]
limit = screendata[1][0][1]; span = screendata[0]

# set initial highlight
oncurrent1 = scr_position(span, limit, get_wposition())
highlight(oncurrent1[0], oncurrent1[1])

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pos = get_wposition()
    # bypass possible incidental failures of the wmctrl command
    if pos != None:
        oncurrent2 = scr_position(span, limit, pos)
        # only set highlight if there is a change in active window
        if oncurrent2 != oncurrent1:
            highlight(oncurrent1[1], oncurrent1[0])
        oncurrent1 = oncurrent2
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `highlight_focus.py`
3. Test- run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/highlight_focus.py
   ```

   *With the second monitor connected*, test if the script works as expected.
4. If all works fine, add it to startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/highlight_focus.py"
   ```

#### Notes

- The script is extremely low on resources. To "save fuel", the screen setup; resolutions, span size etc. is read only once, during startup of the script (not included in the loop). That implies that you have to restart the script if you connect/disconnect the second monitor.
- If you added it to startup applications, it means you have to log out/in after changes in monitor configuration.
- If you'd prefer another brightness percentage for the dimmed screen, change the value in the line:

  ```
  action2 = "xrandr", "--output", scr2, "--brightness", "0.6"
  ```

The value can be between `0,0` (black screen) and `1.0` (100%).

#### Explanation

[image]

On startup of the script, it determines:

- the spanning resolution of both screens
- the x-resolution of the left screen
- the names of both screens

Then, in a loop (once per second), it:

- checks the position of the active window with the commands:

  - `wmctrl -lG` (to get the list of windows and their positions)
  - `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` (to get the id of the frontmost window)

If the window's (x-) position is greater then the x-resolution of the left screen, the window apparently is on the right screen, *unless* it is greater then the spanning size of the two screens (then it would be on the workspace on the right). therefore:

```
if limit < pos < span:
```

determines if the window is on the right screen (where `limit`is x-res of the left screen, `pos` is the window's x-position and `span` is the combined x-res of both screens).

*If* there is a change in the position of the frontmost window (on left screen or right screen), the script sets the brightness of both screens with the `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr --output <screen_name> --brightness <value>
```

---

### EDIT

#### Dim-flash the focussed screen instead of a permanent dimmed "unfocussed" screen

As requested in a comment and in chat, below a version of the script that gives a short dim flash on the newly focussed screen instead:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
In a side-by-side dual monitor setup (left-right), the script below will give
a short dim- flash on the newly focussed screen if the focussed screen changes
"""

import subprocess
import time

def get_wposition():
    # get the position of the currently frontmost window
    try:
        w_data = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
        frontmost = subprocess.check_output(["xprop", "-root", "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"]).decode("utf-8").split()[-1].strip()
        z = 10-len(frontmost); frontmost = frontmost[:2]+z*"0"+frontmost[2:]
        return [int(l.split()[2]) for l in w_data if frontmost in l][0]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def get_onscreen():
    # get the size of the desktop, the names of both screens and the x-resolution of the left screen
    resdata = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8")
    if resdata.count(" connected") == 2:
        resdata = resdata.splitlines()
        r = resdata[0].split(); span = int(r[r.index("current")+1])
        screens = [l for l in resdata if " connected" in l]
        lr = [[(l.split()[0], int([s.split("x")[0] for s in l.split() if "+0+0" in s][0])) for l in screens if "+0+0" in l][0],
               [l.split()[0] for l in screens if not "+0+0" in l][0]]
        return [span, lr]
    else:
        print("no second screen seems to be connected")

def scr_position(span, limit, pos):
    # determine if the frontmost window is on the left- or right screen
    if limit < pos < span:
        return [right_scr, left_scr]
    else:
        return [left_scr, right_scr]

def highlight(scr1):
    # highlight the "active" window, dim the other one
    subprocess.Popen([ "xrandr", "--output", scr1, "--brightness", "0.3"])
    time.sleep(0.1)
    subprocess.Popen([ "xrandr", "--output", scr1, "--brightness", "1.0"])

# determine the screen setup
screendata = get_onscreen()
left_scr = screendata[1][0][0]; right_scr = screendata[1][1]
limit = screendata[1][0][1]; span = screendata[0]

# set initial highlight
oncurrent1 = []

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pos = get_wposition()
    # bypass possible incidental failures of the wmctrl command
    if pos != None:
        oncurrent2 = scr_position(span, limit, pos)
        # only set highlight if there is a change in active window
        if oncurrent2 != oncurrent1:
            highlight(oncurrent2[0])
        oncurrent1 = oncurrent2
```

Comment: +1. I always love your answers Jacob. Nice work.

Comment: I had to change `limit < pos < span` to `limit <= pos < span` to get it working. Anyway this is really nice. However I'm not sure if I want to have it working this way (dimming the other screen). I'll try to modify it to make single bright 'pulse' when active screen changes.

Comment: I've also added exit handler, it resets screen brightness to normal value. (so it won't stay dimmed when I've killed script during testing). Not sure if I should add it here - I'm not much into python, so I'm not sure if I did it right (but it works)

Comment: I've edited it your answer and added it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27375/discussion-between-korda-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: @korda See may (latest) edit. Should be pretty reliable now.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Wow! you rock

Comment: @dhiya wow, thanks! This is *so* nice to get done :)

Comment: Hmmm.... where is the "+2" button? Thanks. Bookmarked.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found another solution, that is bit different from what I wanted in the first place, but works fine too.

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins`
2. Run ccsm
3. In `Effects` section enable `Animations` plugin
4. In `Focus Animation` edit and select desired animation.

Only wave effect worked... So if you don't like it, you will have face as sad as mine.

Comment: Dodge also works for me, but only when the raising window was hidden or partly-hidden behind another. Fade gives an odd, unpleasant flash.