# Dual display. Software dimming

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-management, shutdown

I got a difficult question.
I have a dual display setup. I sometimes watch a movie from the left screen and always have to reach for the power button to shutdown the right display during the movie. Is there a way to do this without having to manually shutdown the display?

Comment: It would be relatively simple to make the right (or any) screen dim to zero if the active *application* running the movie is on either one of the screens (as an altered version of this: http://askubuntu.com/a/665365/72216), but that would also mean the other screen would dim if only the application would be active, but the movie not (yet) running. Would that be a downside or a problem?